# android app Toolbar.setTitle error Attemp to invoke virtual method 'void.androidx.appcompat.widget'

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Trying to create android simple app using this code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("mytitle");
```

and this

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("mytitle");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in Android X both of them can't use, please help how to set title toolbar?

Comment: Can you share your activity layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing the wrong toolbar class, or rather two different toolbar classes in xml and java code

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("mytitle");
```

This code should work

Comment: It is exactly what the OP reported in the question.